# Is it safe to eat pumpkin seeds with peel?

Tags: food-safety, seeds, pumpkin

I dried pumpkin seeds but now don't have the patience to peel them one by one. Could I just eat them with the skin? I suppose I could but they won't taste very good. Therefore, bonus question: in which form could pumpkin seeds with peel be used? So far I would try to blend them and put some in dough for bread.

Answer (score 5):

We never peeled them growing up.

We'd coat them in some oil, roast them in the oven (stirring occasionally), then season them when they came out.

Comment: Roasted and salted unpealed ones are common in South Europe too. Northern of the Alps are often served at buffet for various salad composition, or on pumpkin soups or bread roll.